# Seeking reference on regularity theory for nonlinear elliptic PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Hello,

I am searching for a reference on a result I know must exist proving regularity for weak solutions of a (nonlinear, but well-behaved) elliptic homogeneous PDE.  Working over say a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be fine, and I don't need to deal with very nonlinear PDE - quasilinear is enough for me.  If someone can help locate a reference, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" by David Gilbarg and Neil S. Trudinger

Comment: Oh, thank you!  I really appreciate it.  Headed to library. :-)